# Ruby: Remove the existing object from an array based on the value when adding a new one

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I am a ruby newbie. I have an array called `users`

```
[
 {'name': 'Andy', 'age': 23, 'position': 'manager'},
 {'name': 'Cindy', 'age': 25, 'position': 'HR'},
]
```

when adding a new object `{'name': 'Dave', 'age': 33, 'position': 'manager'}` to the array, it always removes the existing item based on the `position` key. So when *Dave* is added to the array, *Andy* should be deleted because his position is "manager". The new array should be

```
[
 {'name': 'Cindy', 'age': 25, 'position': 'HR'},
 {'name': 'Dave', 'age': 33, 'position': 'manager'},
]
```

My current solution keeps the old item and removes the new item, which is wrong :(

```
users.append(user).uniq do |user|
  user.position
end
```

I am looking for a clean and short way to achieve it. Thank you.

Comment: _adding a new object to the array `{...}` : This `{...}` is not an Array. `users` in, of course, an Array.

Comment: BTW, `'name': 'Cindy'` is equivalent to  `'name'.to_sym => 'Cindy'`, so you could write it simpler as `name: 'Cindy'`. After all, your keys are Symbols, not Strings.

Comment: @user1934428 Thank you, I have edit that sentence to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the matching element `index`, `delete_at` that index, and then `insert` the new element at that index.  Something like this:

```
 users = [
 {'name': 'Andy', 'age': 23, 'position': 'manager'},
 {'name': 'Cindy', 'age': 25, 'position': 'HR'},
]

user = {'name': 'Dave', 'age': 33, 'position': 'manager'}

index = users.index{|i| i[:position] == user[:position]}
users.delete_at(index)
users.insert(index, user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You wish to replace an element of an array `arr`, so you need to determine the index `i` of the element in the array you wish to replace (using [Array#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-index), a.k.a. `find_index`), then simply set `arr[i]` equal to the replacement value. (See [Array#[]=](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D).) This of course *mutates* (modifies) the original array. We can write a simple method to do that.

```
def sub_hash(arr, replacement_hash, hash_to_replace_name)
  i = arr.index { |h| h[:name] == hash_to_replace_name }
  arr[i] = replacement_hash
  arr
end
```

Let's try it.

```
arr = [{name: 'Andy', age: 23, position: 'manager'},
       {name: 'Cindy', age: 25, position: 'HR'}]
replacement_hash = {name: 'Dave', age: 33, position: 'manager'}
hash_to_replace_name = 'Andy'
```

```
sub_hash(arr, replacement_hash, hash_to_replace_name)
  #=> [{:name=>"Dave", :age=>33, :position=>"manager"},
  #    {:name=>"Cindy", :age=>25, :position=>"HR"}]
```

Now:

```
arr
  #=> [{:name=>"Dave", :age=>33, :position=>"manager"},
  #    {:name=>"Cindy", :age=>25, :position=>"HR"}]
```

confirming that `arr` has indeed been mutated.

The method would have to be modified appropriately if the array does not necessarily contain a hash `h` for which `h[:name] #=> 'Andy'` or if the original array is not to be mutated. To avoid mutating `arr` you could write:

```
def sub_hash(arr, replacement_hash, hash_to_replace_name)
  i = arr.index { |h| h[:name] == hash_to_replace_name }
  adup = arr.dup 
  adup[i] = replacement_hash
  adup
end
```

---

Note that the hash keys are all symbols. For example, `'name': 'Andy'` is shorthand for `:'name'=> 'Andy'` which is the same as `name: 'Andy'`. When defining a symbol quotes are only needed when the symbol contains whitespace (`:'my key'`) or begins with a character other than a letter (`:'007'`). Ruby returns the following:

```
{'name': 'Andy', 'age': 23, 'position': 'manager'}
  #=> {:name=>"Andy", :age=>23, :position=>"manager"}
{name: 'Andy', age: 23, position: 'manager'}
  #=> {:name=>"Andy", :age=>23, :position=>"manager"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another more streamlined approach:

```
users = [
 {'name': 'Andy', 'age': 23, 'position': 'manager'},
 {'name': 'Cindy', 'age': 25, 'position': 'HR'},
]

user = {'name': 'Dave', 'age': 33, 'position': 'manager'}

users.map {|a| a[:position] == user[:position]? user : a}
```